# How to install gcov-tool to RHEL?

Tags: rhel, software-installation

I thought that gcov-tool is part of gcc standard package, which is true for Ubuntu. But unfortunately it's not true for RHEL.

I didn't succeed to find RHEL package name to install gcov-tool. Does anybody know it?

What should I write in my terminal to get gcov-tool installed (with exactly same version, as gcc & other dev-tools)?

I've tried to install all Development Tools (`yum group install "Development Tools"`), it installed successfully, but `gcov-tool` wasn't installed.

There is next list of RHEL versions where I need gcov-tool:
rhel6.6-x86_64
rhel6.7-x86_64
rhel6.8-x86_64
rhel6.9-x86_64
rhel7.0-x86_64
rhel7.1-x86_64
rhel7.2-x86_64
rhel7.3-x86_64
rhel7.3-x86_64
rhel7.4-x86_64 
rhel7.5-x86_64
rhel7.6-x86_64

Comment: Running a search for `gcov-tool` on http://rpm.pbone.net/ gives a few CentOS matches. CentOS is binary compatible with RHEL. Please edit your question and let us know _exactly_ which version of `gcov-tool` you need and which RHEL you run (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?)

Comment: Thank you, updated. I thought there may be a unified command to install package for current version. It should be performed in AWS automatically (using python script).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install one of the `devtoolset` packages via `yum`. I recommend `devtoolset-8` as it's the latest and it's what you'll have in Ubuntu. `devtoolset-6` and `devtoolset-7` also have it if you prefer one of those.

First, make sure that the `rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms` repos is enabled. You can just enable them all:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel*
```

After that, install `devtoolset-8`:

```
yum install devtoolset-8*
```

Then, add the gcc from devtoolset to your environment:

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
```

You can then see `gcov-tool` available:

```
which gcov-tool
```

It will be located in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin`.

Another way to get `gcov-tool` is to build `gcc` from source but that's far more complicated

Comment: No, I'm looking for `gcov-tool` to merge `gcda` files. `gcov` can't merge them. 
`gcov` is installed, btw, by default.
Then, when I'll get merged set of `gcda` files, I will generate cobertura xml using `gcovr`, which is python wrapper over `gcov`.
But for merging I need `gcov-tool`

Comment: that's what I have on Ubuntu 18.04:
`gcov (1)             - coverage testing tool` and `gcov-dump (1)        - offline gcda and gcno profile dump tool` and `gcov-tool (1)        - offline gcda profile processing tool`
So `gcov-tool` is not `gcov`

Comment: In RHEL 7.4 I have just `gcov (1)             - coverage testing tool`, and I'm looking for a way to install `gcov-tool`

Comment: @Arkady See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you, will try tomorrow and accept as answer if it helps

Comment: After execution of first command, I got this:
`Error: 'rhel*' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.`
Then I've tried it `subscription-manager repos --list` and got this `This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.`

Comment: @Arkady Is the machine actually registered with Red Hat? Add the output of `subscription-manager status` to your question.

Comment: No, and it founds out that machines which called "redhat", and it's written inside them, are "centos" in fact with some funny issues (here is facepalm's sign). So, among them we also have real redhat, I've checked it there and your answer is a working way to achive the goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that people who will search for this solution in fact need a way to get one report from many sources.

And they meet next problems:

- among different operating systems it needs to perform different steps to achieve tools
- *.gcda from different OS or compiler versions sometimes can't be merged
- machine where you run merge may not be same machine as one where you compiled your binary (which will produce incompatible gcda's), even may not have same OS

So, general way to achieve the goal was just to convert *.gcda to any markup text format (such as html or xml) and then use one of existing tool to merge those reports, not matter where and on which OS.

This doesn't answer the question above, but this idea may be helpful for people who once meet question above.

PROS: you just forget about binary differences and OS relative tools.

CONS: size of set of *.gcda is 20-50 times less than size of it's XML representation.